# How to display different sizes for inactive items in Tumbler component

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to build an application and for the time settings i am trying to use Tumbler component for this item. I checked on qml documentation for Tumbler but i couldn't find any size settings for Tumbler. I can change the whole Tumbler font size but what i am looking for is changing the sizes for not current items. If i choose time as 12:24:AM i want to see 11,13,23and 25 on some different font sizes. Here is the example

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

Rectangle {
width: frame.implicitWidth + 10
height: frame.implicitHeight + 10

function formatText(count, modelData) {
    var data = count === 12 ? modelData + 1 : modelData;
    return data.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + data : data;
}

FontMetrics {
    id: fontMetrics
}

Component {
    id: delegateComponent

    Label {
        text: formatText(Tumbler.tumbler.count, modelData)
        opacity: 1.0 - Math.abs(Tumbler.displacement) / (Tumbler.tumbler.visibleItemCount / 2)
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        font.pixelSize: fontMetrics.font.pixelSize * 1.25
    }
}

Frame {
    id: frame
    padding: 0
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Row {
        id: row

        Tumbler {
            id: hoursTumbler
            model: 12
            delegate: delegateComponent
        }

        Tumbler {
            id: minutesTumbler
            model: 60
            delegate: delegateComponent
        }

        Tumbler {
            id: amPmTumbler
            model: ["AM", "PM"]
            delegate: delegateComponent
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The line of "font.pixelSize: fontMetrics.font.pixelSize * 1.25" is changing the whole component's font size. How can i change font sizes for upper and lower values on Tumbler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your `font.pixelSize` by checking `Tumbler.displacement === 0` as follows:

```
        font.pixelSize: Tumbler.displacement === 0
                            ? fontMetrics.font.pixelSize * 1.25
                            : fontMetrics.font.pixelSize
```

After looking at @folibis answer, it inspired me to write this variation which causes the font to diminish in value the further it is away from the current item:

```
        font.pixelSize: fontMetrics.font.pixelSize * 1.25 / ( 1 + Math.abs(Tumbler.displacement))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Tumbler.displacement](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-tumbler.html#displacement-attached-prop) property that represents how far away this item is from being the current item.

```js
Tumbler {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    model: 60
    delegate: Text {
        text: modelData
        font.pixelSize: 16 + Math.abs(Tumbler.displacement) * 10
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this information but can i use this to change that items' font sizes, which are not current ones?

Comment: Did you try this example? That changes all the items font, relative to the current one. the further away from the current element, the font is larger.

Comment: Sure i did but it did the opposite of what i wanted to have, than i removed *10 and added 10/ Math.babs(Tumbler.displacement) and its fine now. Only issue is upper value is staying way far from current one and lower value is staying too close. Its probably about Tumbler.displacement and will figure it out somehow. Thank you!